# Labyrinth Puzzle

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, mazes

<sub>*Part of the [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #35: Restricted Title 1](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6352/fortnightly-topic-challenge-35-restricted-title-1)*</sub>

---

Surprised no one went for this low hanging fruit yet

Get from MAZE to DONE

When you're DONE with the MAZE, apply the following the changes: -- You can probably game this puzzle by working back and forth, but I would prefer if you do the maze first ignoring the changes. You'll probably have more fun. =D

+0 +2 +2 -14 -10 +5 +0 +7 -17 +6 +15 +5 -7 -5 -5 -1 -7 +7 -14 -9 -6 +1 +4 +15

This MAZE DONE at your final answer.

[image]

Comment: You're on a roll with all of these puzzles!

Comment: Can the words be the same at times?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The way this maze works is:

> Each square can be associated with a four-letter word. We can move from square A to square B if the words differ in only one position, that is, we can form a word ladder with the words we go through.

However, there is a catch:

> If we just try to follow a simple path to the end, we realize it's actually impossible! This is because some squares are actually clues for **multiple** four-letter words, and some squares will have to be used more than once!

The path through the maze:

> [image]

The final answer:

> Taking the changed letters at each step of our word ladder, and adding the offsets, we get:
>
>  [image]
>
>  This maze done at **MIDNIGHT**. (according to OP, this was meant to be a pun: as this puzzle was posted on May 31, it indicates that this *May's done* at midnight.)

Comment: +1 for thinking outside the box. I didn't know you could go to multiple boxes at once. +1 respect because you just lost sleep :D

Comment: oath is a type of saying

Comment: Damn. Did not pick up on the reentry.